# Acessing other views workingSet

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin, and I want to use the workingSet selection of the other windows in mine, too. I tried to get all selected working sets (besides the invisible ones) by the workingSetManager, however for some reason it does not give me the selection. It returns all working sets...

```
IWorkingSetManager workingSetManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
return workingSetManager.getWorkingSets();
```

Comment: What do mean by 'selected working sets'? Selected where?

Comment: I mean the working sets that are supposed to be shown. There is like a checkbox in eclpise where u can select the ones you want to see.

Comment: Check box where? Individual views can select which working sets they show, these are private to the view.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a way to get the ones selected in a certain view? I want to have the ones that ar ein the package view and have them set in my own view.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Window > Working Sets' menu item (you may have to customize the perspective to see this) configures the active working sets for the current page. You can get this set by using `IWorkbenchPage.getWorkingSets()`

Individual views may be configured not to use working sets, or to use the workbench page working set, or to use a set configured in the view. Each view does this differently and I don't think there is a defined way to find out which the view is using.